# Error in model User instantiation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i´m starting a simple project where i´m trying to create the crud and give permissions to some users.

I´m programming in python-flask and my database is Postgres.

Python version - 3.6.5 /
Postgres - 10.3 /
Flask 0.12.2

When i try to add user to my db it gives me this error:

> `__init__()` takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

**add_user.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>This is a tittle </title>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="/post_user">
        <label> Email: </label>
        <input id="email" name ="email" type="text" />
        <label> Password: </label>
        <input id="password" name ="password" type="password" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required

#check Block tags - importante para poupar linhas de codigo 

#Create app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost/projetofinal'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True
#Set the application in debug mode so that the server is reloaded on any code change & helps debug
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH'] = 'bcrypt'
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = '$2a$16$PnnIgfMwkOjGX4SkHqSOPO'

# Create database connection object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add')
def add():
    return render_template('add_user.html')
# <> - dynamic url routing
# login_required - Need to be logged to acess this section
@app.route('/profile/<email>')
@login_required
def profile(email):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    return render_template('profile.html',  user=user)

@app.route('/post_user', methods=['POST'])
def post_user():
    user = User(request.form['email'], request.form['password'])
    db.session.add(user) #add object
    db.session.commit()  #save 
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass named arguments to instantiate a user model:

```
User(email=request.form['email'], password=request.form['password'])
```